# Unity game crashing when loading level on older Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a Unity 3d game built for Android which crashes when transitioning from a 'loading' scene into the level. The loading scene is used for preloading images and videos from urls, so some objects are carried from the loading scene into the level

This works fine on a higher end device (A Samsung Galaxy S20 FE), but when tested on an older tablet (A Lenovo Tab 7) the app crashes when loading into the level. I've used logcat through Unity to look at the console and there aren't any error messages, the app just closes.

My guess is that it's a memory issue as Unity requires 1GB minimum RAM while the tablet has only 1GB, but I can make it work by loading directly into the game level and then loading the images and videos afterward. This does cause stuttering however.